# How to use ArrayCollection and ArrayList in AS3.0 in flash professional mx.collection

Tags: actionscript-3

Can we use the mx.collection package in as3.0 flash professional (not in flash builder) ? If yes, from where can i get the whole mx package?

Comment: You would want to download the Flex SDK

Answer (score 0):

ArrayCollection is part of the Flex framework, you would need to include the Flex framework in your CS5 project. I'm not sure if this is possible.